# ERROR 000875: Output raster is an invalid output workspace

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, viewshed, error-000875

The following script uses the function viewshed2 and works without problems:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
import os
import datetime

#Input parameters
location = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
antenna_height = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
maximum_reach = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

#Folder where the script is
script_folder = sys.path[0]
working_folder = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))

#Input variables
fc_Opt_Prospect = os.path.join(working_folder, 'Optimity_Equipment.gdb', 'Optimity_Prospect')
fc_London_Bldngs = os.path.join(working_folder, 'London_Building.gdb', 'London_Buildings')
DSM_model = os.path.join(working_folder, 'Data4Optimimty\ESRI_UK_Bluesky_DSM\ESRI_UK_Bluesky_DSM.gdb', 'DSM_25cm_2015')
fc_Market_Data_2017 = os.path.join(working_folder, 'Data4Optimimty\ESRI_UK_Market_Location_11_2017\Esri_UK_Market_Location_Addresses_11_2017.gdb', 'Market_Location_Addresses_11_2017')

#Selecting new prospect
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_Opt_Prospect, 'fl_Opt_Prospect')

#Adding default values to fields
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'OFFSETA', antenna_height)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'OFFSETB', 0)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'AZIMUTH1', 0)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'AZIMUTH2', 360)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'VERT1', 1)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'VERT2', -16)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'RADIUS1', 0)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'RADIUS2', maximum_reach)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'ESTATE', "\"Prospect\"")
arcpy.AddSurfaceInformation_3d('fl_Opt_Prospect', DSM_model, 'Z', 'BILINEAR')
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'OFFSETC', "!Z! + !OFFSETA!")

#Calculating viewshed
VS2_agl_raster = os.path.join(working_folder, 'Optimity_Temp.gdb', location + '_Viewshed_AGL_Raster')
VS2 = Viewshed2(in_raster=DSM_model, in_observer_features='fl_Opt_Prospect', out_agl_raster=VS2_agl_raster, analysis_type='FREQUENCY', refractivity_coefficient=0.13, surface_offset=0, observer_offset='OFFSETA', inner_radius='RADIUS1', outer_radius='RADIUS2', outer_radius_is_3d='3D', horizontal_start_angle='AZIMUTH1', horizontal_end_angle='AZIMUTH2', vertical_upper_angle='VERT1', vertical_lower_angle='VERT2', analysis_method="PERIMETER_SIGHTLINES")
```

However, when I place the geodatabase 'Optimity_Temp' within a folder (the reason I'm doing this is because I intend to move all my geodatabases to a folder called 'DATA'), the script stops working:

```
#Import geoprocessing.
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
import os
import datetime

#Input parameters
location = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
antenna_height = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
maximum_reach = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

#Folder where the script is
script_folder = sys.path[0]
working_folder = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))

#Input variables
fc_Opt_Prospect = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Optimity_Equipment.gdb', 'Optimity_Prospect')
fc_London_Bldngs = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\London_Building.gdb', 'London_Buildings')
DSM_model = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Data4Optimimty\ESRI_UK_Bluesky_DSM\ESRI_UK_Bluesky_DSM.gdb', 'DSM_25cm_2015')
fc_Market_Data_2017 = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Data4Optimimty\ESRI_UK_Market_Location_11_2017\Esri_UK_Market_Location_Addresses_11_2017.gdb', 'Market_Location_Addresses_11_2017')

#Selecting new prospect
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_Opt_Prospect, 'fl_Opt_Prospect')

#Adding default values to fields
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'OFFSETA', antenna_height)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'OFFSETB', 0)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'AZIMUTH1', 0)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'AZIMUTH2', 360)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'VERT1', 1)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'VERT2', -16)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'RADIUS1', 0)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'RADIUS2', maximum_reach)
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'ESTATE', "\"Prospect\"")
arcpy.AddSurfaceInformation_3d('fl_Opt_Prospect', DSM_model, 'Z', 'BILINEAR')
arcpy.CalculateField_management ('fl_Opt_Prospect', 'OFFSETC', "!Z! + !OFFSETA!")

#Calculating viewshed
VS2_agl_raster = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Optimity_Temp.gdb', location + '_Viewshed_AGL_Raster')
VS2 = Viewshed2(in_raster=DSM_model, in_observer_features='fl_Opt_Prospect', out_agl_raster=VS2_agl_raster, analysis_type='FREQUENCY', refractivity_coefficient=0.13, surface_offset=0, observer_offset='OFFSETA', inner_radius='RADIUS1', outer_radius='RADIUS2', outer_radius_is_3d='3D', horizontal_start_angle='AZIMUTH1', horizontal_end_angle='AZIMUTH2', vertical_upper_angle='VERT1', vertical_lower_angle='VERT2', analysis_method="PERIMETER_SIGHTLINES")
```

It throws the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Arcpy_Scripts\Viewshed_MarketData.py", line 45, in <module>
    VS2 = Viewshed2(in_raster=DSM_model, in_observer_features='fl_Opt_Prospect', out_agl_raster=VS2_agl_raster, analysis_type='FREQUENCY', refractivity_coefficient=0.13, surface_offset=0, observer_offset='OFFSETA', inner_radius='RADIUS1', outer_radius='RADIUS2', outer_radius_is_3d='3D', horizontal_start_angle='AZIMUTH1', horizontal_end_angle='AZIMUTH2', vertical_upper_angle='VERT1', vertical_lower_angle='VERT2', analysis_method="PERIMETER_SIGHTLINES")
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 7615, in Viewshed2
    analysis_method)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 7594, in Wrapper
    analysis_method)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 506, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000875: Output raster: .\Optimity_Temp.gdb\Viewshe_DSM_25c1.tif's workspace is an invalid output workspace.
ERROR 000581: Invalid parameters.
Failed to execute (Viewshed2).
 Failed to execute (ViewshedManyPointsCombinedMarketData).
```

I find this really odd. Any ideas what could be causing the error?

Comment: Look at the error message, this is not a valid path `.\Optimity_Temp.gdb\Viewshe_DSM_25c1.tif`

Comment: But I have no idea where that path comes from. The bit 'Viewshe_DSM_25c1.tif' is not mine.

Comment: Try printing the value of `VS2_agl_raster` before using it in Viewshed2 which is complaining about the value it is being given.

Comment: I have actually done this before I raised the issue here. I have now done it again and this is what it shows => "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\DATA\Optimity_Temp.gdb\test_Viewshed_AGL_Raster", which is exactly what it's meant to be.

Comment: Try setting [`arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/scratch-workspace.htm) to a folder.

Comment: That has actually worked. Now, I really don't understand why there's no need to set "arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace" at all if I don't have the geodatabase 'Optimity_Temp.gdb" into a subfolder. I've gone through the notes on the ESRI site (Scratch Workspace (Environment setting)) but I still don't get it. Any help to undersdand this much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/scratch-workspace.htm) to a folder.

From the usage notes for scratch workspace:

- If neither the scratch or current workspace is set, the autogenerated output path will be the workspace of one of the inputs.

It seems like the `Viewshed2` tool is outputting intermediate temporary rasters in GeoTIFF format and your scratch workspace is defaulting to your input FGDB.

Comment: Could you please point me to what would be the input FGSB in my script? I still fail to see why it works with => " "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Temp.gdb\test_Viewshed_AGL_Raster" but not with =>  "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\DATA\Optimity_Temp.gdb\test_Viewshed_AGL_Raster"

Comment: @PitrakoJunior, not sure. But `script_folder = sys.path[0]` is not a good idea. You should use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` or `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])` instead.